# NotificationListenerService not call onNotificationPosted or onNotificationRemoved

Tags: android

I don't know why the NotificationListenerService  not work for me, It seems so simple but not works for me.I find a lot of didn't solve my problem.At fitst I thought my service is killed .So I use the adb to check the notification

```
adb shell dempsys notification
```

its show me my service not live ,but I don't know why my Service be killed

```
 Notification listeners:
    All notification listeners (2) enabled for current profiles:
      ComponentInfo{com.example.user.myservicedemo/com.example.user.myservicedemo.MyListernService}
      ComponentInfo{com.meizu.battery/com.meizu.power.apps.appnotification.PermanentNotificationService}
    Live notification listeners (5):
      ComponentInfo{com.android.systemui/com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar} (user -1): android.service.notification.INotification
Listener$Stub$Proxy@37943ab SYSTEM
      ComponentInfo{android.ext.services/android.ext.services.notification.Ranker} (user 0): android.service.notification.INotificationListener$Stu
b$Proxy@e821a08 SYSTEM GUEST
      ComponentInfo{com.flyme.systemuitools/com.flyme.systemuitools.SystemuitoolsApplication} (user 0): android.service.notification.INotificationL
istener$Stub$Proxy@b83b5a1 SYSTEM
      ComponentInfo{com.meizu.battery/com.meizu.power.apps.appnotification.PermanentNotificationService} (user 0): android.service.notification.INo
tificationListener$Stub$Proxy@3f193c6
      ComponentInfo{com.flyme.systemuitools/com.flyme.systemuitools.aod.model.AODModelImpl} (user 0): android.service.notification.INotificationLis
tener$Stub$Proxy@a066f87 SYSTEM
```

MyListernService

```
   public class MyListernService extends NotificationListenerService {

    private boolean mStartCompatibility ;
    public static MyListernService instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.e("test","onCreate");
        instance = this;
        mStartCompatibility = getApplicationInfo().targetSdkVersion
                < Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR;
        if (startService(new Intent(this, KeepLiveSevice.class)) == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't find " + KeepLiveSevice.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("test","onStartCommand");
        toggleNotificationListenerService();
        return mStartCompatibility ? START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY : START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);
        Log.e("test","onNotificationPosted");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        super.onNotificationRemoved(sbn);
        Log.e("test","onNotificationRemoved");
    }

    @Override
    public void onListenerConnected() {
        super.onListenerConnected();
        Log.e("test","onListenerConnected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onListenerDisconnected() {
        super.onListenerDisconnected();
        Log.e("test","onListenerDisconnected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        instance = null;
        Log.e("test","onDestroy");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void toggleNotificationListenerService() {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this, com.example.user.myservicedemo.MyListernService.class),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this,com.example.user.myservicedemo.MyListernService.class),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    }
}
```

and the MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(!isNotificationListenerEnabled(this)){
            openNotificationListenSettings();
        }
        startService(new Intent(this,MyListernService.class));
    }

    public boolean isNotificationListenerEnabled(Context context) {
        Set<String> packageNames = NotificationManagerCompat.getEnabledListenerPackages(this);
        if (packageNames.contains(context.getPackageName())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void openNotificationListenSettings() {
        try {
            Intent intent;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS);
            } else {
                intent = new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
            }
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

the keepLiveService

```
public class KeepLiveSevice extends Service {


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (MyListernService.instance == null)
            throw new RuntimeException(MyListernService.class.getSimpleName() + " not running");

        //Set both services to foreground using the same notification id, resulting in just one notification
        startForeground(MyListernService.instance);
        startForeground(this);

        //Cancel this service's notification, resulting in zero notifications
        stopForeground(true);

        //Stop this service so we don't waste RAM.
        //Must only be called *after* doing the work or the notification won't be hidden.
        stopSelf();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 10;

    private static void startForeground(Service service) {
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(service).getNotification();
        service.startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <service android:name=".MyListernService"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
       <service android:name=".KeepLiveSevice"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to give access to the notifications for your apps.

Basically go to your phone's Settings > Notifications then authorize your app to have an access to notifications

Comment: That is the purpose of `openNotificationListenSettings` and also not the issue.